# All Preinstalled Python packages automatically included in the new Virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, macos-catalina

I have this problem since moving from BASH to ZSH in macOS Catalina and trying to remove python 2, which is not successful, so I give up to remove the python 2. And as a result, every time I create new Virtualenv, all global package is automatically included in the new Virtualenv:

here is my configuration:

```
dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % python --version
Python 2.7.16
dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % python3 --version
Python 3.7.6
dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % which python        
/usr/bin/python
dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % pip3 -V
pip 19.0.3 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % which pip   
pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip
dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3

dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv

dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % virtualenv test

created virtual environment CPython2.7.16.final.0-64 in 534ms
  creator CPython2macOsFramework(dest=/Users/dlintin/DEVELOPMENT/DJANGO/belajar_django/test, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/dlintin/Library/Application Support/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1)
  activators PythonActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,BashActivator

dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % source test/bin/activate

(test) dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % pip freeze

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
altgraph==0.17
appdirs==1.4.3
asn1crypto==1.3.0
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.1
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
bonjour-py==0.3
cffi==1.14.0
configparser==4.0.2
contextlib2==0.6.0.post1
cryptography==2.8
cycler==0.10.0
distlib==0.3.0
enum34==1.1.9
filelock==3.0.12
future==0.18.2
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
importlib-resources==1.0.2
ipaddress==1.0.23
kiwisolver==1.1.0
macholib==1.14
matplotlib==2.2.5
modulegraph==0.18
numpy==1.16.6
pathlib2==2.3.5
pbr==5.4.4
py2app==0.21
pycparser==2.19
pyobjc-core==5.3
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==5.3
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==5.3
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==5.3
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==5.3
pyobjc-framework-Automator==5.3
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==5.3
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==5.3
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==5.3
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==5.3
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==5.3
pyobjc-framework-CoreServices==5.3
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==5.3
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==5.3
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==5.3
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==5.3
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==5.3
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==5.3
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==5.3
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==5.3
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==5.3
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==5.3
pyobjc-framework-Message==5.3
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==5.3
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==5.3
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==5.3
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==5.3
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==5.3
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==5.3
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==5.3
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==5.3
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==5.3
pyobjc-framework-Social==5.3
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==5.3
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==5.3
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==5.3
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pyparsing==2.4.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
scandir==1.10.0
scipy==1.2.3
six==1.14.0
stevedore==1.32.0
subprocess32==3.5.4
typing==3.7.4.1
virtualenv==20.0.7
xattr==0.9.7
zipp==1.2.0
(test) dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django %
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you want to be creating a virtualenv for python3? If so, you need to pass that as an argument to virtualenv when created. eg. `virtualenv test --python $(which python3)`. The command for `pip` will still appear as `pip` in your venv, but it will be for python3.

Comment: i've edited the question,  i mean look at the pip freeze at the bottom, all the package already there, even if i just create the venv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is `pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip` 
after cleaning the alias with `unaliased pip` the problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Pip will be included every time in any virtual environment you create. 
pip is required to add new libraries like you used pip for installing freeze of Django.

Comment: i've edited the question,  i mean look at the pip freeze at the bottom, all the package already there, even if i just create the venv.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `which python` while your virtual env. is activated. I had a similar problem lately where the Python in the activated virtual env. would just point to the system python. I'm using Win7x64 and have Python installed in symlinked directories. Are you using symlinks too? Sorry to disapoint you, but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: here's the result: 

`dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % source bin/activate
(belajar_django) dlintin@Linns-MBP belajar_django % which python

/Users/dlintin/belajar_django/bin/python`